# protractor wait timeout catch and continue

Tags: protractor

I have a piece of code in protractor to do a wait:

```
public waitForElement() {
    return browser.wait(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element(by.id('#someEl'))),
        10000,
        'Unable to find the element'
        );
}
```

My issue is that I cannot seem to catch this exception if it times out. I tried adding a catch() clause, which does not work, e.g.:

```
this.waitForElement()
    .then(() => { /* do something */ })
    .catch(() => { /* handle the error -- this code never happens if there is a timeout!!! */ });
```

I tried putting the code in a try-catch block, but that doesn't help either:

```
try { this.waitForElement().then(() => { }); }
catch (ex) { /* this exception is never caught, the test just fails!! */ }
```

I'm stumped: how can I catch the wait timeout and continue with the test without the test failing?

Comment: Hi, what is the error that is thrown in the log of Protractor. Secondly, what happens if you catch the error withig the `waifForElement()` method instead of outside the method?

Comment: Good idea but the result is the same -- the test fails without giving me the chance to catch the exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created a simple testcase for this, see below

```js
// conf
exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['example_spec.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },
  allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
};

// Spec
describe('Wait for element', () => {
  it('element will be found', () => {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

    waitForElement(element(by.css('.hero')))
      .then(() => {
        console.log('element is found');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error = ', error);
      });
  });
  it('element will NOT be found', () => {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

    waitForElement(element(by.css('.heroic')))
      .then(() => {
        console.log('element is found');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('element is not found, do something different');
      });
  });
});

function waitForElement(element) {
  return browser.wait(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element),
    3000,
    'Unable to find the element'
  );
}
```

This gives me the following output

```
 ~/wswebcreation/contributions/protractor  npm run test.example

> protractor@5.1.2 test.example /Users/wswebcreation/contributions/protractor
> node ./bin/protractor example/conf.js

[10:32:17] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:32:17] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/
Started
element is found .
element is not found, do something different.


2 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 6.917 seconds

[10:32:24] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[10:32:24] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

So it looks like it works

You can also do something like this with your method

```js
function waitForElement(element, maxWaitTime, failOnError) {
  maxWaitTime = maxWaitTime || 10000;
  failOnError = failOnError || false;

  return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element), maxWaitTime)
    .then((found) => Promise.resolve(found))
    .catch((waitError) => {
      if (failOnError) {
        return Promise.reject(`waitForElement: ${waitError} for expected condition ${expectation} for the element: ${element}`);
      } else {
        return Promise.resolve(false);
      }
    });
}
```

This makes it more "flexibel", you can catch the error in the method and if needed let it fail there, else pass a boolean that you can use to go further.

Comment: There was a flaw in my test that manifested itself in the call to waitForElement() -- thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: I'm observing strangeness because I'm calling waitForElement() in a beforeAll() method, and when waitForElement() throws an exception, Jasmine begins executing the beforeEach() while beforeAll() is still in progress. The beforeAll() method still continues, but only after beforeEach() is finished executing. I have no idea why, but Jasmine seems to have problems with the exception being thrown in the beforeAll()

Comment: Can you place you complete script in your initial question?

Comment: The script pretty complicated at this point because it checks two tables for certain data and creates the data if it's not in the tables. Somehow in this process of checking/creating data the promise chain is messed up and I cannot figure out why or where it's being corrupted. I found a way around it by creating a promise that gets resolved when beforeAll finishes, and having beforeEach wait on that promise before beginning. If I can find the time I'll create a simple scenario demonstrating the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Un-picking the particularly important part from @wswebcreation's useful answer: in order to make this work, I've found you *must* specify an explicit timeout.

The following *works*:

```
return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(...), 5000)
  .catch(() => { throw new Error('my error'); });
```

But this *does not*:

```
return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(...))
  .catch(() => { throw new Error('my error'); });
```

giving:

```
 Error: function timed out after 11000 milliseconds
     at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\project\node_modules\cucumber\lib\user_code_runner.js:91:22)
     at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
```

Where 11000 is just the default Protractor timeout we have configured.

Note also that although the [documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) for `browser.wait` implies that the promise form is only required if you want to pause all Javascript execution, not just WebDriver:

> This function blocks WebDriver's control flow, not the javascript
>   runtime. It will only delay future webdriver commands from being
>   executed (e.g. it will cause Protractor to wait before sending future
>   commands to the selenium server), and only when the webdriver control
>   flow is enabled.
>
> This function returnes a promise, which can be used if you need to
>   block javascript execution and not just the control flow.

...it is apparently also *not* possible to catch the result of a timeout-less, promise-less `browser.wait` in a try-catch, as the condition runs in a `setTimeout`.

The above all apparently true with protractor 5.3.2 when used with protractor-cucumber-framework 4.2.0.